# AWS Drop-In Auth In Kotlin Comes Up Blank

Tags: android, kotlin, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I'm trying to use AWS Cognito's drop-in auth (SignInUI) in my Kotlin Android app, and have it redirect to my MainActivity on login, but it's pulling up a blank screen: [image]

I used amplify to create the cognito-pools, using the default settings.

**SignInActivity**

```
class SignInActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in)

        AWSMobileClient.getInstance().initialize(applicationContext, object : Callback<UserStateDetails>{
            override fun onResult(result: UserStateDetails?) {
                Logger.d(result?.userState)
                when (result?.userState) {
                    UserState.SIGNED_IN -> {
                        val i = Intent(applicationContext, MainActivity::class.java)
                        startActivity(i)
                    }
                    UserState.SIGNED_OUT -> showSignIn()
                    else -> {
                        AWSMobileClient.getInstance().signOut()
                        showSignIn()
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onError(e: Exception?) {
                Logger.e(e!!.localizedMessage)
            }

        })
    }

    private fun showSignIn() {
                AWSMobileClient.getInstance().showSignIn(this@SignInActivity,
                    SignInUIOptions.builder().nextActivity(MainActivity::class.java).build())
    }
}
```

I've tried two other versions of the showSignIn() function:

```
    private fun showSignIn() {
        AWSMobileClient.getInstance().initialize(this) {
            val config = AuthUIConfiguration.Builder()
                .userPools(true)
                .backgroundColor(Color.BLUE)
                .canCancel(true)
                .build()
            val signInUI = AWSMobileClient.getInstance().getClient(this@SignInActivity, SignInUI::class.java) as SignInUI
            signInUI.login(this@SignInActivity, MainActivity::class.java).authUIConfiguration(config).execute()
        }.execute()
    }
}
```

and

```
private fun showSignIn() {
    AWSMobileClient.getInstance().initialize(this) {
        val ui = AWSMobileClient.getInstance().getClient(
            this@SignInActivity,
            SignInUI::class.java) as SignInUI?
        ui?.login(
            this@SignInActivity,
            MainActivity::class.java)?.execute()
    }.execute()   
}
```

my **awsconfiguration.json**

```
{
    "UserAgent": "aws-amplify-cli/0.1.0",
    "Version": "1.0",
    "IdentityManager": {
        "Default": {}
    },
    "AppSync": {
        "Default": {
            "ApiUrl": "https://[redacted].appsync-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/graphql",
            "Region": "us-west-2",
            "AuthMode": "AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS"
        }
    },
    "CredentialsProvider": {
        "CognitoIdentity": {
            "Default": {
                "PoolId": "[redacted]",
                "Region": "us-west-2"
            }
        }
    },
    "CognitoUserPool": {
        "Default": {
            "PoolId": "[redacted]",
            "AppClientId": "[redacted]",
            "AppClientSecret": "[redacted]",
            "Region": "us-west-2"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem. Maybe this will help someone.

Using Android Studio I've created an empty activity that I'm using to invoke sign in code and I've named that activity class "SignInActivity". Android Studio automatically created  some other files like for example layout files. Now here comes the funny part. Android Studio created layout file for my empty activity, placed it in "src\main\res\layout\" directory and called it "activity_sign_in.xml", which by coincidence has the same name as layout file for aws-android-sdk-auth-ui-2.16.9 library which in my case is located in here ".gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/5ee42e7f988d8fd14d66f8143c5901b8/jetified-aws-android-sdk-auth-ui-2.16.9/res/layout/activity_sign_in.xml"

Now when com.amazonaws.mobile.auth.ui.SignInActivity starts it calls `setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);`. In my case that has loaded my empty activity's layout instead of layout provided in aws-android-sdk-auth-ui-2.16.9 lib.

**Solution was to change the name of my layout xml file to something different than activity_sign_in.xml.**

Looking at your code, this should work for you too.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Quickstart guide on Authentication: https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/android/authentication#drop-in-auth

This simple version has worked for me recently when I tried it with a new Android project:

```
AWSMobileClient.getInstance().showSignIn(this, new Callback<UserStateDetails>() {
@Override
public void onResult(UserStateDetails result) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onResult: " + result.getUserState());
}

@Override
public void onError(Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "onError: ", e);
}
});
```